# Customize 'appendix' heading

Tags: formatting, chapters, appendices

My appendices are rather small and I want them to come one after another (like `\section`) without the blank page before `\chapter{}` (due to `openright` option). Another problem is that chapter headings take a lot of vertical space above and below them.

How can we remove or decrease these spaces? so that `\chapter` behaves almost like `\section`.

Take a look:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
...
\begin{appendices}
\appendixpage
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc

\chapter{}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Reservoir relative permeability chart ($k_r$ vs. $S_w$).}
\begin{tabular}{c}
...
```

Take a look:
[Output http://8pic.ir/images/25061788036600309756.png](http://8pic.ir/images/25061788036600309756.png)

I wish I was clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the space with `\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}` to be like `\section`.

I don't know about the `open<?>` option of the `book` class, but with KOMAscript you can change that option later on:

```
\documentclass[open=right]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Eins}
\lipsum[1-5]
\chapter{Zwei}
\lipsum[6-10]

\backmatter\KOMAoptions{open=any}
\chapter{Uno}
\lipsum[11-15]
\chapter{Due}
\lipsum[16-20]
\end{document}
```